# How to limit `set-key-partition-list` to one certificate

Tags: security, keychain

TLDR: How can I find make `security set-key-partition-list` run against a single entry, rather than everything in the keystore?

---

I was facing issues with a cipher mismatch with an dotnet/aspnet app and a self signed cert:
[image]

Eventually I found [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27132#issuecomment-553048843), which led me to

```
log stream --process <PID_OF_SECURITYD>
```

Giving:

```
 securityd: [com.apple.securityd:integrity] failure extending partition
 securityd: [com.apple.securityd:security_exception] MacOS error: 32
 securityd: [com.apple.securityd:clientid] code requirement check failed (-67050), client is not Apple-signed
 securityd: [com.apple.securityd:integrity] ACL partition mismatch: client teamid:UBF8T346G9 ACL ("cdhash:71c6a2e36e9b3aa01232049c467ebbad51311b9")
```

Searching from there gave me [this SO question(!)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64017267/16505654), which suggested

```
sudo security set-key-partition-list -D localhost -S unsigned:,teamid:UBF8T346G9 $(security login-keychain)
```

And voila, this worked - I can now use this certificate to run the app locally.

But, that command ran against ~2489 entries, rather than the 1 that I expected.

**So**, how can I find make `security set-key-partition-list` run against a
single entry, rather than everything in the keystore?

It seems that `security find-key` has completely different args that don't seem to match - I either get no results, or ~2489 results.

I've even got to the point of spelunking through [the source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-59306.61.1/SecurityTool/macOS/keychain_find.c.auto.html) to try and figure this out, but I didn't get very far.

Answer (score 0):

Answering as a co-worker of Matt Richardson the OP.

We were loading a certificate into the keychain using .NET (specific versions dotnet 6 on macOS 13.5 and earlier. If you are using a later version of dotnet you may wish to re-evaluate this)

The normal macOS behaviour when loading a certificate into the keychain, is that when an application first tries to use it (more specifically the certificate's associated private key), a permission prompt will appear onscreen, asking the user to authorize the operation. Applications are represented by "teams", which tie back to Apple developer account teams.

For the `dotnet` executable, the "team" ID is UBF8T346G9 which is tied back to Microsoft's Apple Developer Account.

For some reason when we used dotnet's `X509Store.Add` method to import a pfx file, it would import the certificate and private key, but would do so in a way that stopped this permission prompt from appearing. When the application tried to use the certificate it would simply fail with no recourse, other than to brute-force `set-key-partition-list` on all the keys in the keychain.

We found that calling out to Apple's `security` command line tool using `security import -f pkcs12 -P passphrase` would import the pfx file correctly.
When the application tries to use the private key, the permission prompt now appears and the user can authorize it successfully.

This does not answer the original question of **"How to limit `set-key-partition-list` to one certificate"** but it does at least clarify why we needed to ask that question in the first place, and how we avoided needing an answer.